Loop through an array/range
I want to find in an array/range if one or more cells have red background color. The output ( cell's address + text ) to be returned in a cell outside of range. I don't have any VBA experience and this is all I came up with so far:
Sub MacroTest()
Dim rng As Range
rng = Range("k2:014")   'the array/range/
i As Object             'the cell
For Each i In rng       'looping through the range
    If i.Interior.Color = 255 Then
        Range("c5").Value = "red"   'the output value will be asigned to a cell outside of range
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
End Sub


There is no question here.  Please see [ask] and [mcve]

Check For Highlighted Cells


There is a difference between highlighting manually or by Conditional Formatting.
The following checks if any cell is highlighted in red by Conditional Formatting, IMO a more reasonable scenario. Also, the range to be checked is referenced dynamically i.e. the code still works after adding more rows of data.

Main
Sub CheckForRedCells()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim sfrg As Range: Set sfrg = ws.Range("K2:O2")
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = ws.Range("C5")
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = RefRangeFind(sfrg, True)
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'If IsColoredCellFound(rg, vbRed, , True) Then ' CF, display message
    'If IsColoredCellFound(rg, vbRed) Then ' CF, don't display message
    'If IsColoredCellFound(rg, vbRed, True, True) Then ' no CF, display message
    'If IsColoredCellFound(rg, vbRed, True) Then ' no CF, don't display message
        
    If IsColoredCellFound(srg, vbRed, , True) Then ' CF, display message
        dcell.Value = "Not OK"
    Else
        dcell.Value = "OK"
    End If
    
End Sub

Help
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the range from the first row
'               of a given range ('firstRowRange') to the bottom-most
'               non-empty row in the range's columns.
' Remarks:      'DisplayMessage' indicates whether to show a message box
'               when there is no data found and where (Default: 'False').
'               The function will fail if the worksheet is filtered.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefRangeFind( _
    ByVal firstRowRange As Range, _
    Optional ByVal DisplayMessage As Boolean = False) _
As Range
    With firstRowRange.Areas(1).Rows(1)
        Dim cell As Range
        With .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
            Set cell = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
            If cell Is Nothing Then
                If DisplayMessage Then
                    MsgBox "No data found in range """ & .Address(0, 0) _
                        & """ of worksheet """ & .Worksheet.Name & """!", _
                        vbExclamation
                End If
                Exit Function
            End If
        End With
        Set RefRangeFind = .Resize(cell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a boolean indicating whether any cell of a range
'               ('checkRange') is highlighted in a given color ('CheckColor').
' Remarks:      'IsNoConditionalFormatting' set to 'False' (Default) indicates
'               that the color is checked in Conditional Formatting.
'               'DisplayMessage' indicates whether to show a message box
'               if no cell with the given color was found (Default: 'False').
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function IsColoredCellFound( _
    ByVal checkRange As Range, _
    ByVal CheckColor As Long, _
    Optional ByVal IsNoConditionalFormatting As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal DisplayMessage As Boolean = False) _
As Boolean
    Dim cell As Range, fc As FormatCondition, IsCellFound As Boolean
    For Each cell In checkRange.Cells
        If IsNoConditionalFormatting Then
            If cell.Interior.Color = CheckColor Then IsCellFound = True
        Else
            For Each fc In cell.FormatConditions
                If fc.Interior.Color = CheckColor Then
                    IsCellFound = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next fc
        End If
        If IsCellFound Then
            IsColoredCellFound = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cell
    If DisplayMessage Then
        MsgBox "No cells with color " & CheckColor & " found!", vbExclamation
    End If
End Function


Tested it out. Works well enough
Sub MacroTest()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("K2:O14")

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If cell.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Value = "Red"  ' Change where needed
            End                                    ' Just exit if we found 1
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub


This should work:
Sub MacroTest()

    Dim rangeToTest As String
    Dim destination As String
    Dim c As Object
    
    
    rangeToTest = "K2:O14"
    destination = "C5"
    
    For Each c In range(rangeToTest).Cells
    
       If c.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
       
           'Debug.Print c.Address

           range(destination) = "red"
           Exit For
           
       End If
    
    Next
    
End Sub


Sub CheckRedBackground()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim redColor As Long
    Dim hasRed As Boolean
    Dim outputCell As Range

    ' Define the RGB value for red color
    redColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    ' To select a range prompt the user
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select the range to check for red background cells", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' We will exit the sub if no input range was provided.
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' Check each cell in the range for red background
    hasRed = False
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Interior.Color = redColor Then
            hasRed = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell

    ' Determine the output cell
    Set outputCell = rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count + 1, 1)

    ' Write "Red" or "Not Red"
    If hasRed Then
        outputCell.Value = "Red"
    Else
        outputCell.Value = "Not Red"
    End If

    ' Inform the user
    MsgBox "Result written to: " & outputCell.Address
End Sub

Check if it works for you. I don't understand the question fully. On the other hand the above code should suffice. Or you can let me know in the comment section and explain the question a bit. Do you also want to count how many red-cells you have inside the range?

You were quite close.
This is what I came up with:
Sub MacroTest()
Dim i As Object                      ' the cell
For Each i In Range("k2:O14").Cells  ' looping through the range
    If i.Interior.Color = 255 Then
        Range("c5").Value = "red"    ' the output value will be asigned to a cell outside of range
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
End Sub

I got rid of rng as it kept causing all kinds of trouble, but still it's a good idea to keep it, as indicated in some other answers.
The most important was your range k2:014, that should obviously become k2:O14 (the letter "O" instead of the digit "0" (zero)).

I did that but apparently I need to have at least 15 reputation, really sorry about that, I will review/upvote the answer as soon as I get those 15 points

@GabrielK: I'm cleaning up my bad posts. Can you decide whether or not to update/accept my answer here? Thanks.
